# inflection points for 3D curve-discrete data

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have set of 3D points denoting a curve .I want to know if the curve is concave up or down.I have smoothed the curve with spline approximation,I want to find the inflection point of the curve which will tell me the curve is up or down.How do I find inflection points with discrete data that I have?
-swetha